# How to get the ARN of a codepipeline inside of the same CDK stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, aws-codepipeline, aws-cdk

I am trying to set up a notification rule as part of a code pipeline in a CDK stack.

*Note this is NOT a CDK pipeline but a CDK stack that is setting up a AWS CodePipeline.*

In order to create a CfnNotificationRule I must pass in the ARN of the CodePipeline as the `resource` parameter. In the sample code below I've hardcoded the ARN as `TARGET_ARN`

However, I would like to provide this dynamically.

**How do I provide the ARN that CDK generates for `my-pipeline` to the `CfnNotificationRule` constructor?**

```
const codepipeline = require('@aws-cdk/aws-codepipeline');

class PipelineStack extends cdk.Stack {

    constructor(scope, id, props) {
        super(scope, id, props);

        //I want the ARN of this pipeline in TARGET_ARN
        new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            crossAccountKeys: false,
            pipelineName: "my-pipeline",
            stages: [{
                    stageName: 'Source',
                },
                {
                    stageName: 'Build',
                },
                {
                    stageName: 'Deploy',
                    ]
                }
            ]
        })



        const AWS_SLACK_CHATBOT_ARN = 'arn:aws:chatbot::111111111111:chat-configuration/slack-channel/my-slack-channel'
        const TARGET_ARN = 'arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-2:111111111111:my-pipeline'

        const notes = new notifications.CfnNotificationRule(this, 'my-dev-slack', {
            detailType: "FULL",
            name: "my-dev-slack",
            eventTypeIds: [
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-succeeded",
                "codepipeline-pipeline-action-execution-failed",
                "codepipeline-pipeline-stage-execution-failed"
            ],
            targets: [{
                targetType: "AWSChatbotSlack",
                targetAddress: AWS_SLACK_CHATBOT_ARN
            }],
            resource: TARGET_ARN

        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initialise the pipeline as a local variable and then you can use its internal methods after, for example your new code would look like this (I noticed you had a bracket `[` under `stageName: 'Deploy',` which  was causing the code note to compile so I have removed it in my example )

```
        const myPipeline = new codepipeline.Pipeline(this, 'Pipeline', {
            crossAccountKeys: false,
            pipelineName: "my-pipeline",
            stages: [{
                stageName: 'Source',
            },
                {
                    stageName: 'Build',
                },
                {
                    stageName: 'Deploy',
                    
                }]
        })

        myPipeline.pipelineArn
```

`myPipeline.pipelineArn` will give you the ARN